# Best practice for ignoring files within a folder with GIT

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm just looking for some advice on the best way to manage the following situation with git.

my project has a folder called "photos" that users can upload images to.

I have a version of the project running locally and I am adding images to this folder for testing purposes.

When I push to the live server I want the "photos" folder to get pushed but not the images within it. Also when users add images to the "photos" folder on the live server I want GIT to ignore them.

I know I need to use Git Ignore but I'm unsure what the best way to do this is.

Should I just add "photos" to the git ignore file and then manually create the "photos" folder on the live server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think photos/* would do what you want (I don't use git)

Comment: Do you have anything *else* in the "photos" folder, other than photos? Note that you can't add a completely empty directory to Git at all.

Comment: No all that would be in the folder would be images. So I suppose just ignoring the whole folder and then manually creating it on the live server would be my best bet.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
echo '*' > photos/.gitignore
git add -f photos/.gitignore
```

Git does not support empty directories, but standard practice for a directory is to create a [`.gitignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file inside it. The `*` entry causes git to ignore anything inside the directory (even the `.gitignore` file itself, hence the `add -f` to override that).